# Transforming columns of data.table based on other data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have two large tables of features (`training_df` and `test_df` set). In the training data, the columns have been normalized to be zero-mean with unit variance and the test data has been scaled using the scaling from the training data.

Before scaling, the raw features were very sparse, and I would like to reconstruct that sparse structure for the modeling. The sparse structure can be recovered by adding the mode of the columns of the training column-wise to both data tables. I can do this efficiently for the training data, but I struggle to find an efficient way to achieve that for the test data. My current attempt is as follows:

```
# Function to calculate mode
mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  as.numeric(ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))])
}

# VERY slow sparsification of columns in test set
for (cn in names(test_df)) { # feature names are identical in data frames
  mode_tmp <- mode(training_df[, ..cn])
  set(test_df, j = cn, value = test_df[, ..cn] - mode_tmp)
}

# Fast sparsification of training set
training_df[, colnames(training_df) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - mode(x)), .SDcols = 1:ncol(training_df)]
```

Comment: Could this time difference be related to the difference in data size? Technically, `set` should be pretty fast too. You could also try changing to `mode_tmp <- mode(training_df[[cn]]); set(test_df, j = cn, value = test_df[[cn]] - mode_tmp)` (don't know if that makes a difference in speed)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Changing from `[, ..cn]` to `[[cn]]` completely solved the problem. If you'll leave an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I was expecting that because your mode function requires atomiv vectos wheres `DT[, ..cn]` returns a data.table, even if cn only is a single column name. Please feel free to answer it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was given by docendo discimus in the comment. The bottleneck of the computation for `test_df` was the mode function. By simply replacing `[, ..cn]` with `[[cn]]` the data table returned an atomic vector instead of a `data.table` and the total time spent calculating the mode was reduced from hours to seconds.